# GitHub-like Markdown editor / preview (OSX)?

Tags: macos, github, editor, markdown

I just want to **preview** markdown before push to GitHub.
I tried a bunch of Editors, but none of them parsed the following:

````
```C#
bool test = polygon.ContainsPoint(point);
```
````

That's all I wanted, but every editor I've tried so far just could not parse it right (at least out of the box). I tried [MacDown](http://macdown.uranusjr.com/), [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), [Marked](http://marked2app.com/) so far.

This [README.md](https://github.com/eppz/Unity.Library.eppz_kit/blob/master/README.md) just falls apart by the end of the file, while GitHub reads it fine.

Can you just suggest a solution that works?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although, your syntax seems right, it looks like using the `csharp` alias is better handled accross editor. See the supported languages/aliases in **[languages.yml](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)** per language from the `linguist` project.

This below:

````
```csharp
bool test = polygon.ContainsPoint(point);
```
````

is perfectly rendered in **[Atom](https://atom.io/)**, for instance, whereas using ```` ```C# ```` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, Atom renders just fine even with `C#`.

Comment: Hmmm. I use the latest Atom. The syntax highlighting doesn't work with `C#`. See this **[screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/pyqAdUC.png)**

Comment: Yap, highlighting breaks indeed, I just need a correct layout to provision. GitHub will do its own coloring anyway.